# NSTextField: integerValue behaving inconsistently

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I have found that `[NSTextField integerValue]` behaves differently with values containing thousands separators depending on how the value was set.

(I am in Germany, so my thousands separator in these examples is a point ".").

- If I call `[myTextField setIntegerValue:4567]`, the text field will contain **4.567** (with tousands separator), and `[myTextField integerValue]` returns 4567.
- If I type the value **4.567** info the text field manually, or use `[myTextField setStringValue:@"4.567"]`, then `[myTextField integerValue]` returns just **4**.

Apparently it stops parsing the number at the thousands separator, even though it inserts such a separator itself when calling `setIntegerValue`.

So I have actually two questions:

1. Is there a setting or other easy way that I can prevent it to format the number when using `-setIntegerValue:` ?
2. Can I "enable" the number parsing to understand/accept thousands separators when calling `-integerValue`? Or, if not, what would be the simplest way to parse a number with thousands separator from an NSString?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a Number Formatter (`NSNumberFormatter`) to the text field in the storyboard or XIB. This makes the contents of the cell and `objectValue` of the text field a `NSNumber` instead of a `NSString`.

> Is there a setting or other easy way that I can prevent it to format the number when using -setIntegerValue: ?

Switch off Grouping Separator of the formatter.

> Can I "enable" the number parsing to understand/accept thousands separators when calling -integerValue?

Switch on Grouping Separator of the formatter and set Primary Grouping to 3.

> Or, if not, what would be the simplest way to parse a number with thousands separator from an NSString?

Use a `NSNumberFormatter`, see the class reference and [Number Formatters](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002368-SW1).

Answer (score 2):

`integerValue` is not locale-aware, it will always use `.` as the decimal point.

You should use `NSNumberFormatter.numberFromString:` instead.

[Link to NSNumberFormatter class reference.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumberformatter?language=objc)